# org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Couldn't read magic numbers to guess format

Tags: java, apache-commons, exif

I am trying to upload an image via jsp and at back end i am trying to read its metadata. But i am getting this error

> org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Couldn't read magic numbers to guess format.

```
final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(file.getBytes());
```

The problem is the object file is of MultipartFile and instead of it, it should be of type File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted Multipartfile in File using below code to avoid the error.

```
 File convFile = new File( multipart.getOriginalFilename());
 multipart.transferTo(convFile);
 final ImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(convFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming the error comes from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/tags/sanselan-0.96-incubator/src/main/java/org/apache/sanselan/Sanselan.java) (hard to say without a complete stacktrace),

```
        int i1 = is.read();
        int i2 = is.read();
        if ((i1 < 0) || (i2 < 0))
            throw new ImageReadException(
                    "Couldn't read magic numbers to guess format.");
```

I assume the upload of the image somehow got corrupted, or the file is wrong. I'd suggest reading the file just from the filesystem, check the first two bytes, and move from there.

Comment: The problem is the object file is of MultipartFile and instead of it, it should be of type File.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by asking it to read an empty stream, so if file.getBytes() was empty this could also occur.